# Is geocomm.com permanently unavailable?

Tags: data

I have been trying to get to some county data from geocomm.com but the website has been down for several days.

Does anyone have information regarding their status?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour] to learn about our focused Q&A format.

Comment: This more appropriate as a question in the [Chat] than in our focused Q&A database.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, `Geocomm.com` is hosted by MindSites Group which according to Google is

> MindSites Group is the leading owner and operator of business-to-business e-commerce websites supporting technical professionals

The [MindSites Group website](http://www.mindsites.com/) also appears to be down, so it may be a web-host issue rather than something at [GeoComm](http://www.geocomm.com/)

Comment: That's as far as I got too. Hoping it's not down forever.

Comment: @fly2279 Looks like it may be permanent